# Minimum area disks with straight-line cycles in $R^3$ as their boundary

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $C=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_i)$ be a cycle of a graph that is drawn in $R^3$ in the shape of an unknot (not knotted) with straight line segments as its edges. Bound a disk $D$ by $C$ ($C$ should be the boundary of $D$). We would like $D$ to have the minimum area subject to the fixed position of the vertices of $C$ (the boundary of $D$).

Clearly such a disk is in the shape of a geometric triangle if $C$ is a cycle with 3 vertices. But what would $D$ look like if $C$ has more than 3 vertices? Are the two following statements true?

1- Say $C$ has four vertices, then the shape of $D$ is not going to be in the shape of two geometric triangles that are glued to each other at a chord of $C$ (it is going to be curved): imagine a cycle with four vertices $a,b,c,d$ where vertices $a,b,c,d$ are not coplanar and bound this cycle with an elastic material (like part of a balloon).

2- Let the local sphere of a vertex $v$ be a very small sphere (a sphere with radius $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is close to $0$) centred at $v$. Is it the case that the intersection of $D$ and the local sphere of the vertices of $C$ would be located on a great circle of the local sphere.

Do you know of any literature that perhaps confirms the above points or maybe describes the shape of such minimum-area disks?

Answer (score 4):

Re your example (1):
The minimal area surface for a [skew quadrilateral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewQuadrilateral.html) was found
by [H.A. Schwartz in 1890](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurface.html):

---

[image: SkewQuad]

          

<sup>(Image from [Ken Brakke](http://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/examples/examples.htm).)</sup>

---

Comment: existing result, from decades ago: given a minimal surface and a corner made up of line segments, the tangent plane of the surface agrees, in the limit, with the plane defined by the line segments. Easy to believe in this case, more surprising if the boundary is two identical squares in parallel planes ( which cannot be too far apart, maybe half the square edge), the surface being required to be annular, i.e. a sort of tube.

Comment: oh, easy proof that there is no connected surface if the planes of the two squares are more than the square's edge length apart. I don't know the biggest ratio in this case, for identical circles it is about 2/3 of diameter.

Comment: Will, do you know where can find a reference for this: "given a minimal surface and a corner made up of line segments, the tangent plane of the surface agrees, in the limit, with the plane defined by the line segments"?

Comment: @WillJagy: I think Hooman doesn't quite understand StackExchange protocal, so I am notifying you of his query.

Comment: Joseph, got it, I will see if I can find something specific. I think it was new, or recent, when I was in graduate school.

Comment: @Hooman  I did remember the author correctly, it was Michael Beeson, most likely in the 1980's; here is a quote from a website of his "What can or must the behavior of a minimal surface be near a place where the boundary forms an angle, e.g. if the boundary is a polygon in 3-space? [Link not yet live, but planned.]"  http://michaelbeeson.com/research/minimalsurfaces/   GOT IT: The behavior of a minimal surface in a corner. Beeson, M. Archive of Rational Mechanics and Analysis, 65: 213-227. 1977.